# Jquery - get first of not class

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML list as follows:

```
<div class="attachment-row">
    <div class="attachment-each"><a class="attachment-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf attachment-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-download attachment-icon"></i><span class="attachment-title">Resignation_069.pdf</span></a><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
    <div class="attachment-each"><a class="attachment-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-word attachment-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-download attachment-icon"></i><span class="attachment-title">ExitInterview-EMP/001.docx</span></a><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
    <div class="attachment-each"><a class="attachment-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-excel attachment-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-download attachment-icon"></i><span class="attachment-title">Checklist.xlsx</span></a><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
    <div class="attachment-each"><a class="attachment-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-image attachment-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-download attachment-icon"></i><span class="attachment-title">Screenshot_20180101.jpg</span></a><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
    <div class="attachment-each"><a class="attachment-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-image attachment-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-download attachment-icon"></i><span class="attachment-title">Pas Foto 2018.png</span></a><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
</div>
```

I will be putting a class `attachment-each-visible` to some of `attachment-each` using jquery, let's say randomly. In the next function I want to add class `attachment-each-visible` to the **first** `attachment-each` that doesn't have class `attachment-each-visible`.

I know how to select the `attachment-each` that is not `attachment-each-visible` this way:

```
$(".attachment-each").not(".attachment-each-visible").addClass("attachment-each-visible");
```

but how to select the first one of it?

Comment: `$(".attachment-each").not(".attachment-each-visible")[0]`?

Comment: `:first`? `.first()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it with the [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) method:

```
$(".attachment-each").not(".attachment-each-visible").first().addClass("attachment-each-visible");
```

Answer (score 1):

using .first():

```
$(".attachment-each").not(".attachment-each-visible").first().addClass("attachment-each-visible");
```

using eq():

```
$(".attachment-each").not(".attachment-each-visible").eq(0).addClass("attachment-each-visible");
```

using JavaScript get():

```
$(($(".attachment-each").not(".attachment-each-visible")).get(0)).addClass("attachment-each-visible");
```

using JavaScript array item selector:

```
$(($(".attachment-each").not(".attachment-each-visible"))[0]).addClass("attachment-each-visible");
```

Comment: Prefer `first()` or `eq()` in this case as the latter two break the element out of the jQuery object, and then create a new jQuery object, where as the first two remove the breaking out of the jQuery step, so they are less work for the script.

Answer (score 1):

No use for jQuery. Even simpler with plain JavaScript. `querySelector` already returns the first item only (in contrast to `querySelectorAll`), and these selectors are supported by any browser that is still relevant, so there is no need for jQuery's magic (and slow) `.not` implementation. Which also saves you 80+ KB if you weren't using jQuery already.

```js
var theFirst = document.querySelector('.attachment-each:not(.attachment-each-visible)');

theFirst.classList.add('attachment-each-visible');
```

```html
<div class="attachment-row">
    <div class="attachment-each"><a class="attachment-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf attachment-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-download attachment-icon"></i><span class="attachment-title">Resignation_069.pdf</span></a><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
    <div class="attachment-each attachment-each-visible"><a class="attachment-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-word attachment-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-download attachment-icon"></i><span class="attachment-title">ExitInterview-EMP/001.docx</span></a><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
    <div class="attachment-each"><a class="attachment-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-excel attachment-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-download attachment-icon"></i><span class="attachment-title">Checklist.xlsx</span></a><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
    <div class="attachment-each attachment-each-visible"><a class="attachment-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-image attachment-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-download attachment-icon"></i><span class="attachment-title">Screenshot_20180101.jpg</span></a><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
    <div class="attachment-each"><a class="attachment-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-image attachment-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-download attachment-icon"></i><span class="attachment-title">Pas Foto 2018.png</span></a><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector  Provided your users are using a compliant browser.

Comment: Jup, like I said, relevant browser. The function exists in IE8+, and CSS3 selectors like `:not` are supported from IE9 onwards. Of course, If you still want to support IE8- then this won't work..

Comment: Does it?  caniuse shows it doesn't show up in IE until 11.  Edit: Ahhh, mdn shows it at IE 8.  Interesting discrepency.

Comment: That's because caniuse doesn't regard those as relevant anymore. But if you click Show all, above the matrix, it will show, ehm, all.

Comment: But I've just upped the dependency to IE10 by adding the use of `element.classList`. ;-)

Comment: Ah snap!  Thanks for that @GolezTrol